# Какой подход использовать для создания визуального конструктора?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, с чего начать. Задача следующая: Предположим что у нас есть определенный сайдбар с dragndrop компонентами, которые можно перетащить на сетку, визуально выстроить иерархию или связать их друг с другом. Некоторые компоненты могут быть текстовые и т. п. некоторые будут логические, в зависимости от ввода пользователя выполнить одно из условий и перейти к соответствующему блоку. Изображение ниже думаю поясняет.

Для сетки нашел решение: https://interactjs.io/
Сохранять хотелось бы все данные в JSON.

Понимаю что вопрос достаточно абстрактный, подскажите куда копать и что можно почитать. Какими путями можно реализовать данный проект? Какие библиотеки можно посмотреть? И по связи компонентов и компиляции JSON хотелось бы каких то best practices.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Только JS, только хардкор!) Это не самая муторная задача...